# Get keys of all child dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of this kind where the values are dictionaries as well the dictionaries can have nested dictionaries in them. like this:

```
data = {'key1': {
              'keya':{ 
                      'keyc': None
                      }    
              'keyb': None
                       
                }
        'key2': {
               'keyi':None, 
               'keyii': None
                }
       }
```

The dictionaries can be many (we don't know how many dictionaries can be there inside the values). How can I get all keys in all values like this?

```
['key1', 'key2', 'keya', 'keyb', 'keyi', 'keyii']
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: dose the order of the keys metter?

Comment: Yes. The parent keys should come first and then all the first children and then second.

Comment: Sounds like a breadth first recursive function.

Comment: Did you want `"keyc"` to be returned?

Comment: Yes. All child keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could get all the keys using recursion

```
def get_all_keys_rec(dic):
    keys = [key for key in dic]
    for val in dic.values():
        if type(val)==dict:
            inner_keys = get_all_keys_rec(val)
            keys.extend(inner_keys)
    return keys

print(get_all_keys_rec(data))
```

output:

```
['key1', 'key2', 'keya', 'keyb', 'keyc', 'keyi', 'keyii']
```

Comment: Correct approach, but the for loop could be:`for val in dic.values():`

Comment: Yes, my bad. I have just noticed it. Thank you!

Comment: No, not bad (+1 btw). Its now more closely expressing the intent.

Answer (score 1):

```py
keys = []

for key, val in data.items():
    keys.append(key)
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        item = val
        while True:
            for k, v in item.items():
                keys.append(k)
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    item = v
                    break
            else:
                break

print(keys)
```

This outputs:

```py
['key1', 'keya', 'keyc', 'key2', 'keyi', 'keyii']
```

Comment: Compare the high score answers. Your output is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive generation, `yield from` should be your partner:

```
>>> data = {'key1': {
...     'keya': {
...         'keyc': None
...     },
...     'keyb': None
...
... },
...     'key2': {
...         'keyi': None,
...         'keyii': None
...     }
... }
>>> def get_all_keys(dct):
...     def gen_all_keys(d):
...         if isinstance(d, dict):
...             yield from d
...             for v in d.values():
...                 yield from gen_all_keys(v)
...     return list(gen_all_keys(dct))
...
>>> get_all_keys(data)
['key1', 'key2', 'keya', 'keyb', 'keyc', 'keyi', 'keyii']
```